# Do I need verticles to program with Vert.x in Java?

Tags: java, server, vert.x

I don't understand very well the concept of a verticle in [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/), I saw it like a separated thread doing some work, I suposse that's because I new in Vert.x-land.

For doing a simple websocket server, do I need verticles? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: still no :-)
You can start developing with vert.x without using verticles at all. For that, you can use the main concepts of [handlers and futures](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_don_t_call_us_we_ll_call_you) in a regular Java application.

The concept of verticles is especially useful in the following situations:

- polyglot programming - every verticle can be developed in another programming language
- scaling - if you have some verticles which contain logic which takes longer or is invoked more often, then you can deploy more instances of that verticle
- distributed applications (aka 'microservices') - when you want to deploy the verticles on different machines.

More information with actual projects can be found in the fresh [blueprint tutorials](http://vertx.io/blog/vert-x-blueprint-tutorials/) which detail some of the different ways of using vert.x.